# Gulp warnings getting started with JointsWP

Tags: node.js, wordpress, npm, gulp, bower

I discovered [JointsWP](http://jointswp.com/) starter theme which looks promising.

However, I'm having troubles getting started with the sass version which I would like to use.

I did a fresh installation of wordpress, and installed the jointswp theme.

When I do npm install, it installs the dependencies.

But when I do 'gulp', I get a bunch of warnings.

Doing gulp watch and gulp styles seems to work but doing gulp vendor-js gives a "Too many errors. (67% scanned)." reply.

When I install a fresh copy of foundation 6 and use the foundation-cli, I have no problems what so ever.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?
[Image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZvhT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the slow response.

Those errors are normal - they're actually warnings. Your code will compile fine.

It looks like JSLint has some "issues" with how some of the Foundation JavaScript is implemented.